# Question about alerts in Oracle 11.2

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, alerts

I inherited an Oracle 11.2 server.  I wanted to see if whomever configured it before me had any alerts configured, perhaps to notify on audit events.

Logging on as sysdba, I issued this command per the examples in https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-8D62D6A0-99F4-465C-B088-5CCF259B7D80.htm#SUTIL1519

```
show alert
```

I got this error:

```
SQL> show alert
SP2-0158: unknown SHOW option "alert"
```

Is there any way from the command line to show what alerts on configured on the server?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Oracle database can generate ["Server-Generated Alerts"](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/monitoring.htm#ADMIN11247).

You can view the alert thresholds in `DBA_THRESHOLDS` view, and query the alerts from the `DBA_OUTSTANDING_ALERTS` and `DBA_ALERT_HISTORY` views.

But I do not think this is what you are looking for. I have yet to see someone who uses this feature specifically and deliberately for alerting and notifications.

Usually there is Enterprise Manager (provided by Oracle) or some kind of monitoring software like Nagios, Zabbix, etc. that periodically logs in to the database, runs its checks, and sends notifications if needed. Still, some companies just simply use custom scripts scheduled in crontab for monitoring the database. Others use custom Scheduler jobs for monitoring. So no, there is no universal way to find what you are looking for.

The command you tried to execute is not a sqlplus command, it can be executed in `adrci`, and all it does it shows the default log of the selected location. Example:

```
[oracle@o71 ~]$ adrci

ADRCI: Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on Tue Sep 18 18:59:29 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

ADR base = "/u01/app/oracle"
adrci> show alert

Choose the home from which to view the alert log:

1: diag/rdbms/etalon/ETALON
2: diag/clients/user_oracle/host_2676003343_107
3: diag/tnslsnr/o71/listener
Q: to quit
```

Comment: Yes, I knew about DBA_THRESHOLDS, etc. before posting. I was hoping I could do this (seeing the actual alert configured to do something based upon something generated from a threshold event)  from the terminal rather than OEM. Thanks though; the feedback is much appreciated!